# Possible to add a “Heading” for the columns in HDF5 format?

Tags: export, data-structures, hdf5-format

A similar post was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451900/hdf5-writing-a-string-header-to-a-file), but it's not using MMA.

A small test to export HDF5 file,

```
Export["test.h5", { "summary_Shoe" -> anssummary, "summary_Tie" -> anssummaryTie}]
```

Woks fine.

[image]

But how could I add some heading for the columns? Like I would do for the Excel?

I tried something like this,

```
Export["test.h5", {   "summary_Shoe" ->    Prepend[anssummary, {"Total B", "Percentage B", "Total P",      "Percentage P", "Total Tie", "Percentage Tie", "Percentage",      "3giving8"}],   "summary_Tie" -> anssummaryTie   },  "DataFormat" -> {"string"}]
```

But I got an error:

> Export::errelem: The Export element Datasets contains a malformed data structure and could not be exported to HDF5 format.